# How do I add a control at design time without using Drag 'n' Drop?

Tags: vb6, user-controls, controls

I'm attempting to create a Wizard type control in VB6 and have run into a stumbling block.

I'd like to allow users of the control to be able to add and manage CWizardPage(s) to the design time control using a property page.

The first approach I used was to add the Wizard pages to the OCX directly using a Collection, however I ran into two problems in that the Collection class is not persistable (and I couldn't find an easy way to make it so) and that VB6 seems very limited in it's ability to instantiate controls at run time - so it would seem to be a struggle to actually re-instantiate them.

My next thought was to just allow the users to draw the wizard pages at design time. This sort of works, however it's far too easy to draw one of the wizard pages inside another wizard page instead of inside the CWizardContainer.

So can anyone please tell me how to add controls to a form at design time without using drag 'n' drop?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add controls to a form or other container (such as a UserControl) using the `Add` method of the container's `Controls` collection. For example, to add a TextBox named `myTextBox` to a form called frmMyForm, you could do this:

`frmMyForm.Controls.Add "VB.TextBox", "myTextBox"`

Here is a snippet from the VB6 help file:

> #### Add Method (Controls Collection)
>
> Adds a control to the **Controls**
>   collection and returns a reference to
>   the control.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> *object*.**Add** **(***ProgID, name, container***)**
>
> The **Add** method syntax has these parts:
>
> *object* (Required)
>
> An object expression that evaluates to
>   an object in the **Applies To** list.
>
> *ProgID* (Required)
>
> A string that
>   identifies the control. The ProgID of
>   most controls can be determined by
>   viewing the Object Browser. The ProgID
>   is composed of the Library and Class
>   of the control. For example, the
>   CommandButton control's ProgID is
>   VB.CommandButton. In cases where the
>   ProgID differs from that shown in the
>   Object Browser, Visual Basic displays
>   an error message that contains the
>   correct ProgId.
>
> *name* (Required)
>
> A string that identifies the member of
>   the collection.
>
> *container* (Optional)
>
> An object reference that specifies a
>   container of the control. If not
>   specified or NULL, defaults to the
>   container to which the Controls
>   collection belongs. You can put a
>   control in any existing container
>   control (such as the Frame control) by
>   specifying this argument. A user
>   control or an ActiveX document can
>   also be a container.

Answer (score 0):

> ...VB6 seems very limited in it's
>   ability to instantiate controls at run
>   time...

Nothing could be further from the truth.  Instantiating controls at run time in VB6 is trivial.

1. At design time, set the Index
   property of the control to 0.  This
   turns the control into a control
   array.
2. At runtime, load new instances of the control as needed.

As an example, create new Standard EXE project drop a TextBox onto the form, set its Index to 0 and put the following in the Form_Load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim newIndex As Integer

    newIndex = Text1.UBound + 1
    Load Text1(newIndex)
    Text1(newIndex).Top = Text1(newIndex - 1).Top + Text1(newIndex - 1).Height
    Text1(newIndex).Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on an application that regularly made many whole data entry screens dynamically based on the desired fields.  It's verbose to specify the Top, Left, Width, and Height all the time.  So, you usually have a "template" of the control and copy those settings to the additional one.